# SSH connect error

Tags: permissions, ssh

I use a notebook with Ubuntu 12.10 and try to connect a server with Ubuntu 12.04.
The server has already installed openssh-server. And allow publick key and password to login.
But I connect the server sometime well but after minutes it will be error.
First, it will show me these messages:

WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
     ...... 
     Add correct host key in /home/myname/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.

but I never reinstall system and the openssh-server. Both are never changed!
The server nerver shutdown or reboot.

Second, after I remove the relative key from my known_hosts and use ssh connect the server again, it will let me type my password.
then my nightmare coming...
 Permission denied (publickey,password)

But I typed the correct password!

PS: I used password and public key both success. But the problem will appear again after i logout then login.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to allow password auth? If so you can edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config to include:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Also make sure these are set correctly for your key auth:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You can also have it ignore your known_hosts file... for debugging only please :)

```
IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes
```

Also ensure you have correct perms on your key files.. ssh is very particular about it:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

Lastly, if all else fails send us output of your session attempt using 'ssh -vvvv'.